# NetCoreApp 3.1 With Identity UI Not signed in on my urls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I've started new project with identity ui, with a custom AplicationDbContext on an Infrastructure project.

The problem is when I signin and I am on a identity url, the navbar is displayed with a signin user:

[image: Working on identity urls]

But when I change to non identity url, for example home page, it seems like the user is not logged in

[image: Identity as not registered on custom urls]

I use this template: https://github.com/JasonGT/CleanArchitecture
But on the Web project I created a new one because I don't need a SPA.

Anyone knows what can be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I did not added

```
services.AddAuthentication();
```

On ConfigureServices